# Retrieving type information from XML in JSON

Tags: jquery, html, xml, json, dom

I am extracting the below XML data.

```
<ArticleIdList>
<ArticleId IdType="pii">S0022-3956(14)00106-X</ArticleId>
<ArticleId IdType="doi">10.1016/j.jpsychires.2014.03.024</ArticleId>
<ArticleId IdType="pubmed">24755258</ArticleId>
</ArticleIdList>


var json4 = $.xml2json(responseXml4);

results += " <td class=\"ms-vb2\">" + json4.PubmedArticle[k].PubmedData.ArticleIdList.ArticleId[0] + "</td>";
```

I was using ArticleId[o] to get "doi" but I found that it is not always the first item like above example. how can I get the "doi" value exactly rather than using ArticleId[o]?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Im using jquery for xml , the code like below ,

the xml parameter will be your xml

```
(function(){

      var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
      $xml = $(xmlDoc);
      var result =  $xml.find('ArticleId[IdType=doi]');
      $("div").text(result.text());

});
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/lacur/1/edit)